# Get day of week from UTC_TIME Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, utc, dayofweek

When I do

```
df.dtypes
```

, appears this

```
utc_time         int64
```

one example of utc_time is:
    1536444323321

I found a code here to change utc_time (epoch) to day of week

```
df['Week_Day'] = 
datetime.fromtimestamp(df['utc_time']/1000).strftime("%A")
```

But i receive this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-124-b3277c232078> in <module>()
      2 # df['intage'] = df['utc_time'].astype(int)
      3 # df['intage'] = df['utc_time'].dt.days
----> 4 df['Week_Day'] = 
datetime.fromtimestamp(df['utc_time']/1000).strftime("%A")

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in 
wrapper(self)
    115             return converter(self.iloc[0])
    116         raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to "
--> 117                         "{0}".format(str(converter)))
    118 
    119     return wrapper

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, convert your column/Series to a datetime object.
`df['column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['column'])`

Then, you have two options:

- Option 1 - use the `.dt` accessor:
  `df['column'].dt.weekday` gives you the weekdays as integers
- Option 2 - use the pandas `Timestamp` object:
  `df['column'].apply(pd.Timestamp.weekday)`

But I really recommend option 1.

Comment: If you like my answer, please don't forget to accept it :)